# Live Agent REST API Daily Limits

Tags: rest-api, governorlimits, liveagent, external-app

We are planning to use LiveAgent REST APIs from an external Application. Details of APIs are available in below link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331168&type=1&mode=1

The external application wants to do the below operations:

- Getting Session ID
- Sending a Chat Request
- Pulling messages from the server
- Sending messages to the live agent user

As Salesforce has a [limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) on the number of inbound API calls, we are concerned about the "**Pulling messages from the server**" feature.

To verify this we executed the below request and found that DailyApiRequests 's "Remaining" parameter didn't decrease after pulling messages from **"Endpoint: chat/rest/System/Messages"** at least 20-30 times.

> curl https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/limits/ -H
> "Authorization: Bearer token" "X-PrettyPrint:1"

**Can someone please confirm if Live Agent REST API calls have any Limits? If yes does it counts towards DailyApiRequests for REST APIs? We couldn't figure it out by Limits Documentation and Limits request.**

Comment: The majority of Live Agent APIs don't count against org limits (remember Snap-ins just uses these APIs also). We don't have documentation on this today unfortunately

 
The main use case customers ask about is API usage around back/forth messages, APIs that facilitate the conversation are not counted. 3 API's that get counted to towards API limits - SessionId, ChasitorInit and ChatEnd

Comment: One of the customers I know was in a similar spot before. They briefly verified the API consumption and has tested the Chat. In their observation, API's are not consumed for active conversation. Start and End of Chat need initial API call. So, if there are 10,000 chat's per day, estimate around 20K API per day consumption. The conversation that happens in between (ChatMessage, ChasitorTyping/sneak peak) does not consume API.

Comment: Hi can you guys please help me with the pooling of messages from server.. How do we know when to call this api i mean let say agent might have send message on 3rd second.. It will be flown automatically to client or we need to poll how can we do that...https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/374437/8102